# Time taken by department to offer the admission decision

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, engineering, international-students

How much time does it take for getting the admission decision after all the required documents are submitted at a university that offers admissions on **Rolling Basis**? I had my application and all required douments submitted before 10 days for *Fall 2015*. Also, my appliacation has been forwarded to the department before a week. How much *time* should it take for *the department* to review my application?

Thank you.

Comment: Your use of "before" is non-standard. Do you mean that you submitted your application 10 days ago and it was forwarded to the department 7 days ago? If so, this is far too short a time to expect a decision in the US. Of course, I'd also be surprised to find a department in the US accepting applications for fall of this year this late even with a rolling admissions calendar.

Comment: @BillBarth , thanks for your suggestion. However, I had asked the department before I applied and they had told me to submit my application along with required documents. So, are there any chance to have the decision within next four weeks?

Comment: I have no idea. You'll need to ask the department that. If they told you it's was OK to submit for Fall 2015 10 days ago, then you will probably get a decision before the semester starts. You might want to check back and see what their plan is.

Comment: @BillBarth Actually, I had confirmed on 15th May that my application can be reviewed. I had applied a month ago, but there was a struggle in receiving my GRE Score. I had to send my score three times and that took rest of the time to have all my documents submitted in order to start reviewing my application. Thanks anyways for your response. I also want to know the environment of this application reviewing process. How often do proffesors check applications and how much time does it require to complete review for each application? Could you please inform me? Thanks again.

Comment: I have no idea. You really need to ask the department what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

The waiting time for a decision depends on the admission process. The admission process itself can vary broadly depending on type and size of the institution.

I can point out two different examples from the German higher education system. I graduated at a public state university of applied sciences where I was member of several committees. Now I work at a private state-recognized higher education institution. The admission processes and concerns, may also apply for US universities.

- For public state universities dealing with 10.000+ applications, all of them have to be checked for formal correctness (documents complete and valid etc.). After checking a local numerus clausus have to be calculated to find the limiting grade needed for admission. Especially in Germany some laws and regulations enforce to fulfill target percentages of e.g. women or handicapped persons. These tasks performed by a handful of staff members can last more than a month. Sometimes German universities publish target dates of submitting the admission mail in the same way they publish application dead lines.
- For private universities, business-, management- or law-schools the application process often is more selective. Admission committees decide not only on base of grades and formal criteria. Some require letters of recommendation, motivation letters, CVs pointing out working experience or social engagement. All these documents must be read and for everyone the committees have to give a recommendation. Depending on the number of staff members concerned with this, the period until one receives the final decision can last weeks up to months.

Comment: A **rolling** application, admission and matriculation implies _for me_ a more selective admission process like for doctoral students or habilitation candiates.